# In CodeIgniter 4 Flashdata displaying code redirecting to again again in the same page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, redirect, codeigniter-4

In the CodeIgniter 4, I am using Flashdata for displaying error or success messages in view page and I am using the below code:

```
<?php
    if(session()->get("success")){
        echo session()->get("success");
    }
?>
```

It is not and as well as it redirect frequent in same page using this code!

Comment: `session()` should not doing redirect. anyway, if you want to check is some key exist in session, you should use `session()->has("success")` instead of `session()->get("success")`

Comment: Thank you so much but is it print boolean value but no problem works done

Comment: no, I don't mean that, using `has()` only on if condition. If you want get value session, you should still use `get()` 

```<?php
    if(session()->has("success")){
        echo session()->get("success");
    }
?>```

Comment: this code is work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [**Flashdata**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?#flashdata) instead of `session`.

> Once you reload the page, flashdata will disappear

```
$session->setFlashdata('item', 'value');
# to rerive
$session->getFlashdata('item');
```

You can warp it with `if` conditions well.

```
if($session->getFlashdata('item')){}
```

---

Read more [`Flashdata` - in codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?#flashdata)